# Changing class of a tag depending on php file name in smarty

Tags: php, css, smarty

In a template, there are some tabs (using HTML) that can have the class attribute to say *active* so they can a bit pop up and tell user visually in which tab he/she is.

The code looks like this:

```
<ul id="top-navigation">
    <li class="active"><span><span><a href="{$smarty.const.SITE_URL}/admin/admin.index.php">Front Page</a></span></span></li>
    <li><span><span><a href="{$smarty.const.SITE_URL}/admin/members.list.php">Members List</a></span></span></li>
    <li><span><span><a href="#">Roll Call</a></span></span></li>
    <li><span><span><a href="#">Schedules 5022</a></span></span></li>
    <li><span><span><a href="#">Schedules 5088</a></span></span></li>
</ul>
```

So I am looking for a way that I can tell which `<li>` element is the current active tab. By default the *Front Page* tab is set to active. So when user clicks on the second tab, I want to set that tab to *active* class.

Here is how I set the template that should be loaded in the php file (in this case *members.list.php*):

```
  $smarty->assign('content', 'admin/members.list'); //members.list.tpl
  $smarty->display('admin/index.tpl');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way of doing it is just set a page variable in smarty depending on the page being viewed and then check against it in the template:

```
$smarty->assign('selectedItem', 'home');

<li {if $selectedItem eq 'home'}class="active"{/if}>
```